# Javascript not firing in dojox.layout.ContentPane

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a pane in Dojo where I use dojox.layout.ContentPane. Reason for this is because I need some javascript to fire when the tab is accessed. In the interest of simplicity, I just want an alert to pop up that the tab has been clicked.

My javascript function is below and it's at the top of the page. (The javascript I am actually going to use is a bit more complicated, it's going to set innerHTML divs in the clicked tab with values from another tab).

```
function onclicktest(){
   alert('Dates have been clicked');
}
```

My HTML is below.....

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.ContentPane" executeScripts="true" data-dojo-props="title: 'Dates'" class="tabBox claro">
<script type="dojo/method" event="onLoad">
onclicktest();
</script>
```

What I have noticed about this is when I reload the page the javascript won't fire at all when the dojox.layout.ContentPane tab is selected.

Any ideas on how I solve this? Once I find an answer I'll update if no one else has.
Many thanks!
Janie

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the version of dojo on our servers was not 1.7 because if it were this would have been a snap. The key is to use dojo 1.7 and the onShow capabilities.
This solved it....

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.ContentPane" executeScripts="true" data-dojo-props="title: 'Dates'" class="tabBox claro" onShow="onclickTest()">
```

Works! Just like that.